# If $p \mid (n^2+4)$ and $n \mid (p^2+4)$, then find the maximum possible value of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $n$ be positive integers with $p<200$ and $p$ is prime. If $p \mid (n^2+4)$ and $n \mid (p^2+4)$, then find the maximum possible value of $n$.

I think it start from $pn \mid (p^2+n^2+4)$, but I can't figure this out yet.

Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please remember to add context to your question. In particular: Where did you come across this question? This gives us information about what kind of knowledge and tools are expected to be used.

Comment: Is this a homework problem or something where you expect a nice solution? Otherwise brute force works here.

Answer (score 2):

That's a great idea to start! One thing you have to be careful about is that if $p \mid n$, then you cannot conclude that $p \mid (p^2 + n^2 + 4)$ and $n \mid (p^2+n^2+4)$ implies $pn \mid (p^2+n^2+4)$. Indeed, one such counterexample is $(p, n) = (2, 8)$. However, I claim that this is the only such counterexample. Do you see why? (Hint: What does $p \mid (n^2+4)$ and $p \mid n$ tell you about $p$? What about $n$?)

Ignoring the one counterexample, we are looking at solutions for $ab \mid (a^2+b^2+4)$. We will also want $a$ to be prime, but we shall worry about this later. Some insight about this constraint can be gained using Vieta Jumping. Let us define $c = \frac{a^2+b^2+4}{ab}$, which we require to be a positive integer, and assume WLOG that $a \geqslant b$. We then have $a$ as a root of $x^2-(bc)x + (b^2+4)$. The other root must be integer (because the sum of the roots is $bc$) and positive (because the product of the roots is $b^2+4$). Let us call this root $a'$.

Now, if $a = b$, then $a^2 \mid (2a^2 + 4)$ forces $a = b = 1$ or $a = b= 2$. Otherwise, we have $a > b$. Since $a > b$, we see that $a^2 > b^2 + 4$ (since we cannot have $a = 2$ and $b = 1$). This means that $aa' = b^2 + 4 < a^2$, or in other words, $a' < a$. Thus, the solution $(a, b)$ yields the "smaller" (lower value of sum of the pair) solution $(a', b)$ with $c = \frac{(a')^2+b^2+4}{a'b}$. We can keep repeating this procedure to yield smaller and smaller solutions, but since it must terminate, we will end up at a solution with $a = b$, i.e. at $(1, 1)$ or $(2, 2)$.

This is great news since we can find all solutions by reversing this process starting from $(1, 1)$ and $(2, 2)$. Even better, we can completely ignore the ones originating from $(2, 2)$ for our purposes, since these will only yield solutions with both $a$ and $b$ even (why?) which means the only solution with one number prime from this case will be $(2, 2)$. The solutions originating from $(1, 1)$ are:
$$(1, 1) \to (1, 5) \to (5, 29) \to (29, 169) \to (169, 985) \to (985, 5741) \to \cdots$$
So the first $5$ are all the solutions where $\min(a, b) \leqslant 200$. From these, you can see that the solution you want is $(p, n) = (29, 169)$ since this maximizes $n$.

Comment: In case you had any doubt, this is also what I found with brute force.